# Chrome renders black tabs when switching monitors

Tags: google-chrome, laptop, multiple-monitors, gpu

There are many reports on Chrome showing black pages - most are related to a specific GPU, or page.

In my case I can easily recreate it. I have a Dell Windows laptop, which I use closed in a docking station, hooked to two monitors (What Mac users call "clamshell mode").
Sometimes I use it without the docking station as a plain old laptop.

#### The Problem:

**Each time** I switch between those two modes, after a few tab switches, the viewport turns black. Restarting chrome fixes the issue.

It is probably a combination of this scenario, my Chrome version, and my GPU.

The result of running `chrome://gpu` can be found in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/seldary/5964034).

#### What have I tried?

The only thing I found online, apart from waiting for a fix is to go to `chrome:flags`, and disable "`GPU compositing on all pages`". It didn't help.

#### The Question:

Is there a solution / workaround for this?

Comment: Please be more clear: add an actual question, include what you've already tried.

Comment: Added an "actual question", and included what I already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is super old, but my fix was to drag the window back to my laptop’s screen, then dragging it onto my main monitor without maximizing the window and then releasing the window and docking it to the top of the screen to go fullscreen again.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question which is referring to a problem that occurs when the laptop lid is closed (so it's screen is not visible/turned off).